# Upload a xml file using emberjs

Tags: file-upload, ember.js

I want to make a file upload with ember.js. I am using ember 1.9 with django the file I want to upload is an xml file i want to give the user the possibility to upload up to 4 files. I have seen some older solutions from back in 2013 but was wander if there is something new you might suggest.

P.S. I am not using ember CLI.

Comment: Have you seen this one? https://github.com/benefitcloud/ember-uploader

Comment: As I understand this needs ember CLI which I do not use but this is what I try to use as guide thanks anyway.

Comment: As far as I know ember droplet doesn't need ember cli.